# Want to get acces inner element of json with loop

Tags: python, json

I want to access with loop the inner element `alias` values of both `dims` and `metrics` present in json and appended in separate `dimsList` and `metricsList` python lists.

```
json_obj = 
{
   "dataset":"246",
   "dims":{
      "Location":{
         "alias":"Location",
         "format":""
      }
   },
   "metrics":{
      "ToTal_Dwell":[
         {
            "agg":"sum",
            "format":"",
            "alias":"ToTal_Dwell"
         }
      ]
   },
   "filters":"",
   "limit":"10"
}
```

expecting result to be like `dimsList = ['Location']` and `metricsList = ['ToTal_Dwell']`

Comment: You should create a [minimal, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to get the best help for your question. As it stands, your question is quite vague and gives no real context as to what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can recursively iterate using `.items()`. every time you see an inner dict you make a recursive call, and an inner list causes a call per inner dict in the list.

try this:

```py
json_obj = {
    "dataset": "246",
    "dims": {
        "Location": {
            "alias": "Location",
            "format": ""
        }
    },
    "metrics": {
        "ToTal_Dwell": [
            {
                "agg": "sum",
                "format": "",
                "alias": "ToTal_Dwell"
            }
        ]
    },
    "filters": "",
    "limit": "10"
}


def extract_inner_values(d, key):
    results = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        if k == key:
            results.append(v)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            results.extend(extract_inner_values(v, key))
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for inner_d in v:
                results.extend(extract_inner_values(inner_d, key))
    return results


dimsList = extract_inner_values(json_obj["dims"], "alias")
metricsList = extract_inner_values(json_obj["metrics"], "alias")

print(dimsList)
print(metricsList)
```

Output:

```
['Location']
['ToTal_Dwell']
```